# How to get bearer token AWS for Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS sagemaker, and I have created an endpoint. I want to test endpoint on postman app. I give endpoint URL and JSON body to postman app. But I get this error that `"message": "Missing Authentication Token"` I need to know from where I 'll get bearer token so that I can give it to postman app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question after searching and reading forums,

The easiest way to get bearer token is to install AWS CLI and configure it, using `aws configure` command.
For configuring, we must need to know access key, secret key, region of user. These things can be get by AWS users section.
After configuration by running this command, `aws ecr get-authorization-token`, we can get authorizationToken. [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-authorization-token.html) This token can be fed into bearer token, along with aws signature (access key and secret key) in authorization menu in Postman app.